# php script to set event on google calendar

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-calendar-api

I am developing a web application in PHP to book appointment.

I have [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) and it works fine. I need also save event on my google calendar, directly. Is it possible?

In google API i found only "how add events on user calendar", not to my calendar.

Comment: If you want to save to a specific google calendar in all cases, without the end-user having to log in, then you need to do that server-side. Have your calendar page send the data about the new appointment to your server (via ajax or whatever) and then use PHP to connect to Google Calendar API and send the data onwards to Google. Authenticate using a Service Account. Google provide a PHP client library to help you with this, and lots of documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a service account you can save directly to your own calendar by granting the service account permission to your calendar.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place the file in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    return getServiceAccountClient();
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed. 
 * array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Code ripped from my [php sample project for Google calendar](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.php) if your interested here is an article on how service accounts work and how to set one up.  [Google development for beginners service accounts](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)